# MongoDB 10m search documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I optimize mongoDB search if I have 10+ million documents in one collection? If anything, please, don't advise me to switch to mysql. I need mongodb specifically

For example one of the logs

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "Some ID"
  },
  "data": {
    "players": [
      "ARTEMKA"
    ],
    "itemName": "Pants",
    "playerIds": [
      12345678
    ],
    "price": 12341,
    "balance": 13134,
    "itemHash": "Some hash"
  },
  "type": "sellItem",
  "timestamp": 1690162524.3318582,
  "date": {
    "$date": "2023-07-24T04:35:24.331Z"
  },
  "dateString": "24-07-2023 04:35:24"
}
```

Here's the filter I'm using
`{"data.players": { "$in": ["SomePlayer"]}}`
It usually returns about 300-500+ documents per query.
And the search can take about 10-20 seconds, but i need to do it faster.

Comment: This question isn't answerable. What is the MongoDB search that you are looking to improve? How many documents typically match and get returned for an execution of the query? In the most broad terms, indexes are the typical approach to improving query performance. But as indexes are created _for queries_ we need information about your queries to advise further

Comment: @user20042973 Here's the filter I'm using {"data.players": { "$in": ["SomePlayer"]}}. It usually returns about 300-500+ documents per query.

Comment: And the search can take about 10-20 seconds

Comment: Create an index on `{ "data.players": 1}` and you should observe a drastic change in performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on `{ "data.players": 1}` helped! Ty to @user20042973